# Node stream returns RangeError only for large files

Tags: node.js

I need to stream 1 billion decimal numbers of PI, then do something (just for testing purpose, I'm getting the length). When I read a file with "1 million" of digits, it returns me the length normally but when reading the file with "1 billion" it returns "RangeError: Invalid string length". Why is this happening if apparently there's nothing wrong with the code?

```
import fs from "fs";

let pi = '';

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('pi-billion.txt', 'utf-8');

readStream.on('data', (chunk) => pi += chunk);

readStream.on('error', (error) => console.log(`error: ${error.message}`));

readStream.on('end', () => console.log(pi.length));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node/v8 has [maximum string length](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_constants_max_string_length)

```
$ node -pe 'buffer.constants.MAX_STRING_LENGTH'
536870888
```

Buffers can be larger

```
$ node -pe 'buffer.constants.MAX_LENGTH'       
4294967296
```

You could leave the buffer/string in chunks (or append the chunks into regular intervals to ease processing) and store them in an array, then the next limit should be nodes available memory.

```
const pi_chunks = []
let pi_length = 0

readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  pi_chunks.push(chunk)
  pi_length += chunk.length
})
```